# javascript object.assign for a only one property without making a copy

Tags: javascript, json

lets say we have object a

`a = { 
    prop1:"something",
    schema:{
        array:[array of object]
    }
}`

and b is 
`b = {
    array:[array of object]
}`

and in the object arrays they have pretty much the same object with different values. I want to create a new object with a.schema updated from b  with object.assign.
so I wrote something like `Object.assign({},a.schema,b)` and it returns me this 
`{
    schema:
    {
        array:[array of object]
    }
}`
.But I don't want to create a copy of a  and then copy this schema into the newly created copy of a. 
I want this
`newObject = { 
    prop1:"something",
    schema:{
        array:[array of object from b]
    }
}`

I want to create a new object which look just like a in a single Object.assign , is that possible?

Comment: You can do `Object.assign({}, a, {schema: b})`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what you can do:

`x = {a:1,b:[1,2,3}}
y = {c:[4,5,6]}
z=Object.assign({},{prop1:x.a},{shcema:y.c})`

Comment: You have to specified the properties

Answer (score 0):

If it's all right to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), you can do this:

```js
const a = {
  prop1: 'something',
  schema: {
    array: [
      {
       aprop: 'prop',
      },
    ],
  },
};
const b = {
  array: [
    {
      bprop: 'test',
    },
    {
      bprop: 'test2',
    },
  ],
};
const updated = {
  ...a,
  schema: b,
};

console.log(updated);
```